# Print processes, sorted by usage of CPU

Tags: linux, process, sort, cpu-usage

I need to print the 10 processes that are using the most CPU. Also I need to print their ID, and the command they were started with.

---

What I've found is that the command `ps -ax -u` prints all the processes and their %CPU usage. The command `ps -ax -u --sort pcpu` prints all the processes sorted by the %CPU usage, from the least to the most, but I need to print only 10 processes from the most to the least. I have to use something like `sort -r` to make a reverse sorting, but the command `ps -ax -u --sort -r pcpu` produces an error.

---

So, how can I make a reverse sorting and print only 10 of the processes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> to print 10 processes, that use the most CPU

```
ps -aux --sort -pcpu | head
```

---

> Sorting syntax is `[+|-]key[,[+|-]key[,...]]`.
>  The "`+`" is
>   optional since default direction is increasing numerical or
>   lexicographic order. Identical to `k`. For example: `ps jax --sort=uid,-ppid,+pid`

---

`head` - will print the first/top 10 lines of file(s) or standard input (by default)

Comment: And, for example, if I need not 10, but 15 lines, I will need to write `head -n 15` ?

Comment: @НиколайЖурба, that's right